# How does Facebook save my browser and recognize it the next time I log in?

Tags: facebook, browser

How does Facebook actually save my browser when I click on save browser i.e do they use my user-agent with combination of MAC id? How does Facebook actually do it?

Comment: The topic you want to read about is called "cookies".

Comment: @reto I too thought it was the cookies. Tried copying all my cookies onto a chrome browser on a different machine with the same configuration and tried connecting and it did not log me in. So Facebook is able to differentiate based on the browser somehow. So if it is based on the cookies it should have worked

Answer (score 0):

http header has all the info regarding the browser and the agent that you are accessing an app with.

Check this image -> https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/511_http/firebug.png

I assume, they take out the header information with respect to the unique user id and save the browser info with your signed in user id.